# can not get X-AppEngine info from req header in 2nd generation AppEngine

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I build 2 functions in GoogleCloudFunctions today, with the same code and different environment (1st gen and 2nd gen).

```js
res.json(req.headers)
```

the 1st generation with X-Appengine-* in headers but 2nd generation don't have it.
1st generation res:

```json
{
    "host": "xxxxx",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2",
    "forwarded": "for=\"xx.xx.xx.xx\";proto=https",
    "function-execution-id": "z93h1p8dezsd",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "traceparent": "00-c6fbb14b26a1999f7203caa810bd82bd-f4e8995eb815facc-01",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "x-appengine-appversionid": "h~j3d1cb91ff7bbe64cp-tp/a8aa78b2557e1c923250159d17af9995:2.447902922919183830",
    "x-appengine-city": "?",
    "x-appengine-citylatlong": "0.000000,0.000000",
    "x-appengine-country": "HK",
    "x-appengine-default-version-hostname": "j3d1cb91ff7bbe64cp-tp.appspot.com",
    "x-appengine-https": "on",
    "x-appengine-region": "?",
    "x-appengine-request-log-id": "63745ec000ff00ff035e0349af4c0001687e6a33643163623931666637626265363463702d7470000161386161373862323535376531633932333235303135396431376166393939353a32000100",
    "x-appengine-timeout-ms": "599999",
    "x-appengine-user-ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "x-cloud-trace-context": "c6fbb14b26a1999f7203caa810bd82bd/17647523771945712332;o=1",
    "x-forwarded-for": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "connection": "close"
}
```

2nd generation res:

```json
{
    "host": "xxxxx.run.app",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "x-cloud-trace-context": "7adcb5fe556c66fc94f83b6dfe62dfe6/5799981330522755859;o=1",
    "traceparent": "00-7adcb5fe556c66fc94f83b6dfe62dfe6-507dac4a5db4d313-01",
    "x-forwarded-for": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "forwarded": "for=\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\";proto=https",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
}
```

Could I get X-Appengine-* from 2nd generation Functions?

Thank you

Comment: Functions Gen2 runs on Cloud Run. If you want those headers, deploy on gen1.

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1):

App Engine-specific headers is not supported for second generation environment.Because Cloud Functions (2nd gen) is built on Cloud Run,you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#new-in-2nd-gen)

As mentioned by john hanley in above comment If you want those headers, deploy on gen1.

If you think it’s a valid feature request you may raise [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#new-in-2nd-gen) with a clear description.Good feature requests will solve common problems or enable new use cases.